# 10 dice rolls sum compared to specific number

Tags: python

I am trying to do a program where one dice gets rolled ten times. The sum of the rolls should be compared with 50. If the sum is bigger than 50 you win.

Please assist.

```
import random

def main():
    print("WELCOME TO ROLLING DICE!!!")
    
    print(" ")
main()

def rollDice():
    
    diceRollvalue = random.randint(1,6)
    
    displayDicePic(diceRollvalue)
    print("You rolled a " + str(diceRollvalue))
    print(" ")
    sum=0
    for _ in range(doMoreRolls):
        sum = diceRollvalue+sum
        print("SUM  " + str(sum) )

def displayDicePic(diceRollValue):
    if diceRollValue == 1:
        print(" ")
        print(" ----- ")
        print("|     |")
        print("|  0  |")
        print("|     |")
        print(" ----- ")
        print(" ")
    elif diceRollValue == 2:
        print(" ")
        print(" ----- ")
        print("|0     |")
        print("|      |")
        print("|     0|")
        print(" ----- ")
        print(" ")
    elif diceRollValue == 3:
        print(" ")
        print(" ----- ")
        print("|0     |")
        print("|   0  |")
        print("|     0|")
        print(" ----- ")
        print(" ")
    elif diceRollValue == 4:
        print(" ")
        print(" ----- ")
        print("|0    0|")
        print("|      |")
        print("|0    0|")
        print(" ----- ")
        print(" ")
    elif diceRollValue == 5:
        print(" ")
        print(" ----- ")
        print("|0    0|")
        print("|   0  |")
        print("|0    0|")
        print(" ----- ")
        print(" ")
    elif diceRollValue == 6:
        print(" ")
        print(" ----- ")
        print("|0    0|")
        print("|0    0|")
        print("|0    0|")
        print(" ----- ")
        print(" ")

def endrollingDice():
        print(" ")
        input("Press Any Key to Exit")
        quit()
        
doMoreRolls = 0

while doMoreRolls<10:
    playerchoice=input("Do you want to Roll Dice? Y/N:")
    if(playerchoice=="Y" or playerchoice=="y" or playerchoice=="Yes" or playerchoice=="yes" or playerchoice=="YES"):
        rollDice()
    else:
            doMoreRolls=False
            endrollingDice()
```

I want to add it to above code.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. If you have a problem with implementing this, add the code you tried to the question, the error you get and show what research you did towards solving it.

Comment: Hey, since all your dice print statements start with the same 2 lines and end with the same 2 lines, you could save code space by printing the 2 lines, then having your `elif` statements for the middle 3 lines, then print the last 2 lines. This assumed you'd never want to change that, of course.

Comment: Another separate comment is that to print an empty line, you can just have `print()`. When you have `print(" ")`, you are unnecessarily adding in a new string. I am assuming here that your goal is just to make a newline, and that you don't care about the ` `.

Comment: Finally, the way you check for "yes" input could be simplified like: `if playerchoice in ["Y", "y", "Yes", "yes", "YES"]`. You could also get fancy with regex, ignoring case, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use library to generate random number

```
import random

answer_list = []

for i in range (10):
    n = random.randint(1,6)
    answer_list.append(n)
    
if sum(answer_list) > 50:
    print('You Win')
else:
    print('You Lose')
```